# pandas left join returning larger matrix and not working

Tags: python, pandas

I have 2 dataframes, the 1st is below "station_anal"

```
        count   Start station number
index       
31623   17105   31623
31258   11432   31258
31201   10194   31201
31200   9505    31200
31247   9145    31247
```

2nd dataframe "vt" is:

```
    Start station number    Start station
0   31214                   17th & Corcoran St NW
1   31104                   Adams Mill & Columbia Rd NW
2   31221                   18th & M St NW
3   31111                   10th & U St NW
4   31260                    23rd & E St NW
```

station_anal is size 486x2

vt size is 8000x2

my left join command is:

```
lj = pd.merge(station_anal, vt, how = 'left', on = 'Start station number')
```

dtypes are the same for both columns namely int64

however lj returns:

```
lj.head()

count   Start station number    Start station
0   17105   31623   Columbus Circle / Union Station
1   17105   31623   Columbus Circle / Union Station
2   17105   31623   Columbus Circle / Union Station
3   17105   31623   Columbus Circle / Union Station
4   17105   31623   Columbus Circle / Union Station
```

of size 8000x3

Makes no sense since my understanding is left join resulting matrix row size is always the first dataframe in this case 486

Comment: can you please include data which others can load in your post, by pasting the output of `df.to_json()` into your post for example.

Comment: Id like to but the data is confidential, the head() above should provide sufficient information as well as the matrix sizes of both dataframes to ascertain the issue.. Thx

Comment: then you should obfuscate it appropriately - you should also be aware that a graph of confidential information is also confidential

Comment: Does dataframe "vt" have 8000 rows with unique "Start Station Number"s?

Comment: no vt repeats, unique Start Station Numbers exists in the first df station_anal, thus there are 486 unique station #s and the left join resulting dataframe on station_anal then too should have 486 rows to my understanding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Let's use map:

<strike>station_anal['Start Station'] = station_anal['Start station number']

.map(vt.set_index('Start station Numer')['Start station'])</strike>

Update drop duplicates then map:

```
mapper = vt.drop_duplicates('Start Station Number')\
           .set_index('Start station number')['Start station']

station_anal['Start Station'] = station_anal['Start station number']\
                                     .map(mapper)
```

Comment: wont work in df vs Start station number is not unique and python is throwing error "Reindexing only valid with uniquely valued Index objects"

Comment: Ah.. so vt has duplicate 'start station number'.

Comment: oh why would the 2nd table in a left join duplicate matter since i thought left join is a simple lookup on for the first table.  In any case thanks I did what you did a bit differenty:

1. vt.drop_duplicates()
2. pd.merge(station_anal, vt, on='Start station #', how = 'left) 

and this worked given the correct size of 486.